# Display image from xml in html Website with simplexml

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have an xml file(xml.php3) that contains `img scr=` path.
I want to show some of the images in my website.
I have try that with text sources of the xml file with simplexml , that works good. But i dont now how to do it with the images.

my xml data for text:

```
<ROOMTYP ID="161792">
    <ID>161792</ID>
    <DISCRIPTION>Rooms for Rent</DISCRIPTION>
```

I use for show in my website:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.php3");

$Element= $xml->xpath('//ROOMTYP[@ID="161792"]');
$Ausgabe= $Element[0];
echo $Ausgabe->DISCRIPTION;
?>
```

my xml data for image:

```
<IMAGES ID="6">
              <ID>6</ID>
              <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://images.img.com/room_pics/zim_238842_006.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
```

How have to write the simplexml code for display that image in my website?

Comment: How do the two bits of XML relate to each other - are they part of the same element?

Comment: Both are separately element in the same xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to identify it by the ID attribute of the IMAGES element, then again XPath can find it for you.  The main difference is that if you have `&lt;` in the text, if you want to decode these you can convert them using `html_entity_decode()`, but you will need to ensure that you cast the result to a string (`(string)`) as the result of `xpath()` is a list on node objects...

```
$element= $xml->xpath('//IMAGES[@ID="6"]');
echo html_entity_decode((string)$element[0]->PIC);
```

gives...

```
<IMG SRC="https://images.img.com/room_pics/zim_238842_006.jpg"
        width="640" height="480" BORDER=0>
```